# Loop through a text file and save each line into a variable dynamically

Tags: python

I'm making this script which would get each line in a text file and save it to a variable.

I started with this but I don't know how to implement a loop to this...

```
f = open("time.txt", "r")
g = open("values.txt", "r")
time = f.read(1)
value = g.read(1)
```

the variable's value depends on the current line in the text file.

- time.txt data are timestamps. sample: `2020-05-29T05:00:00Z`
- values.txt data are positive numbers. sample: `24`

Comment: Can we get example text files?

Comment: Shouldn't you create a real dictionary instead of a string?

Comment: It seems you need to read a Python [tutorial or book](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F). There are too many things which are missing here to explain in one answer.

Comment: it seems what you actually want to do is merge the content of two different text files and combine it in a `dict`?

Answer (score 1):

you can strat with looping on a file and append the lines to list then do what ever you like with the list. **you can do the work while iterating on the file lines (it depends on your code demands and task)**.:

reading the file line by line then use the context manger with for reading files in general.

Technically, in Python, an iterator is an object which implements the `iterator protocol`, which consist of the methods `__iter__()` and `__next__()`. since file are folowing the iterator protocol you can read them with for loop:

```
lines=[]
with open (fileName,'r') as fP:
    for line in fp:
        lines.append(line)
        #...............................
        # or do the work on this line! #
        #...............................
```

you can use the method read(). which return a list of lines of the text file:

```
lines=[]
with open (fileName,'r') as fP:
    lines=fp.read()
```

No need to call close(). this is handle by the context manager after exiting the with block the file will be closed.

you can loop throgh the list and append them to new `dict` or do what ever you need:

```
for each_line in lines:
    #do my work on line here.
```